# VSC writing own extension, autocompleting with variable and prefix &x_VariableOne

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, vscode-extensions

How can I tell my extension to look first for `&s_`?
One solution would be to rename all variable to capital prefix `S_`, but this is not an option in my scenario.

I am working on an [extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api) for Visual Studio Code(VSC). Variable are defined as followed:

```
  &i_ Var_Six`
  &s_ SampelTwo
  &...
```

The implementation in VSC is done by "direct implementation" like that:

```
let provider1 = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider({ language: 'test' }, {

    provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken, context: vscode.CompletionContext) {
        vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider
        var completions = new Array();
        for (let knownElement of TestVar) {
            completions.push(new vscode.CompletionItem(knownElement));
        }
        return completions;
    }
});
context.subscriptions.push(provider1);
```

Now the problem I have is, that the autocompleting looks first for capital letters but also recognizes the `&` not as part of the variable.

What I want is that I can start typing "s_" and it would suggest all known variables starting with "&s_".

What VSC actually is suggesting for input “s_” is "i_Var_Six". This is because it looks for the capital letter “S” (camelcase) and the char “ _ ” it does not recognize the char “&” because it is defined as a “word separator”.

Comment: can you please show what arguments you pass to the `vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider` function, if i understand the problem might it be related to the triggerCharacters.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure why `&` doesn't work, this is the closest way of implementing it, that i know of.

(read the comments)

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  const TestVar: string[] = ['&_awd', '&_Awd', '&_213', '$_34', '$_23'];
  let provider1 = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
    { language: 'plaintext' },
    {
      provideCompletionItems(
        document: vscode.TextDocument,
        position: vscode.Position,
        token: vscode.CancellationToken,
        context: vscode.CompletionContext
      ) {
        var completions = [];
        for (let knownElement of TestVar) {
          const item = new vscode.CompletionItem(knownElement);
          // i added this so that the first & sign gets removed, 
          // you might want to add a check so that this edit only gets added when the user typed a & sign. 
          item.additionalTextEdits = [
            { newText: '', range: new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(position.line, position.character - 1), position), },
          ];
          completions.push(item);
        }
        return completions;
      },
    },
    '.',
    '&' // add this so that the completions get triggered when the user types the & sign.
  );
  context.subscriptions.push(provider1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your "clean up", it works with `$`.
However I still have the Problem, because I actually use `&` instead of `$`, sorry for that I chanced it because `$` is more often used.
So why does it work with `$` but not with `& ` and how can I change that?

Comment: @RaLo i updated my answer, i don't know if you can do what you want to do.

Comment: @Sylver Thank you again, I really appreciate it! But still it is not really what I want. If I do it like this it will correctly find the item after the `&_` but what I actually want is that it only gives me vars that starts with eg. Input `&s_`, `&s_awd`, `&s_Awd` but not `&f_`...
I think the solution could be “Word Pattern”, I just tried it, but with no success…
[link](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide#word-pattern)